# see files/folders from heroku dashboard

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, server

I recently use Heroku for deploying my app.
Is there a feature that allows me to see which files I uploaded to Heroku , for example in any Github repo I can see all my files/folder structure and I can view them and change them.
I can't find anything like this inside Heroku dashboard and I wonder if this feature exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can see but via Heroku CLI.
If currently you are in your app which you pushed to heroku you can directly run

> heroku run ls

Else you can use following command for a specific app

> heroku run bash --app

Note: Login before you run.

You can also log into your heroku account and do it from the dashboard as you can see on the photo:

[image: step by step to access console on heroku dashboard]
Once the console is opened you can run normal terminal commands, such as:

> ls
>
> cd dirname
>
> cat filename
>
> etc...

Comment: thanks but how can I open files ? consider I have /logs/someFile.log ... when I open console from dashboard I type 'heroku run bash' and then 'cd logs' ... now I want to open someFile.log

Comment: Yeah you can do it by **cat someFile.log**.